# Flot draw graph pop out window

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I can't for the life of me work out how to do this.

What I want to do is have flot, after getting the data from an Ajax query, write the graph to a JavaScript pop out window.

Is this possible?

//Edit, added code

```
function generatePieChart(graph_id, objData, hyperlinks, newwindow) {

    var data = objData;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var num = parseInt(objData[i][1]);
        if(hyperlinks == true){
            data[i] = { label: "<a class='user_pie_link super_light_box' id='"+objData[i][0]+"'>"+objData[i][0]+" <span style='float: right;'>"+objData[i][1]+"</span></a>", data: num }
        }
        else{
            data[i] = { label: "<p id='"+objData[i][0]+"'>"+objData[i][0]+" <span style='float: right;'>"+objData[i][1]+"</span></p>", data: num }
        }

    }

    $.plot($(graph_id), data,
    {
        series: {
            pie: {
                show: true,
            },
            legend: {
                show: false
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So this is what I had so far, i've gotten rid of my messing around, I was trying to use window.open(...); but that didn't appear to work, what I need is on the first instance it writes the chart to a standard div, when newwindow = true, it will create a new browser window and then write the graph to that.

Comment: Do you have any code to show..?

Comment: By "pop out window", do you mean something like this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/?  Without knowing how you are creating this window, there's little we can do to help.